# How do I remove computer name from the command line prompt?

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

Is any way to remove my computer name from command line prompt?

I want the prompt to look like this:

```
αғsнιη:~$
```

Instead of this:

```
αғsнιη@αғsнιη-pc:~$
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit your `.bashrc`, change `PS1` to:

```
PS1='\u:\w\$'
```